# Error while importing project Google signin sdk

Tags: cocoa-touch

When I Import project Google signin sdk, reported this error:

[image]

How to solve it?

Comment: Give code sample of what cause the error in order to be helped.

Comment: NSError* configureError;
    [[GGLContext sharedInstance] configureWithError: &configureError];
    Add this code to the

Comment: More details please

Comment: I was in accordance with the method provided by the official website use cocoapod . in appdelgate inter NSError* configureError; [[GGLContext sharedInstance] configureWithError: &configureError];   demo is good